# angularJS: unable to load a custom service?

Tags: angularjs

I am having a hard time getting my custom service to work.

I am getting the error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: trucosProvider <- trucos
```

Here is my code:

the service declaration:

```
var trucos = angular.module('trucos', []);
trucos.factory('agregarSignoPorcentajeAFila', function(palabraClave,numeroDeColumnas) {
    //numeroDeColumnas=# de columnas a la derecha de palabraClave 
    //que queremos afectar          
    var celdaCreci = $("td").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == palabraClave;
    }).closest("td").nextAll().slice(0, numeroDeColumnas);

    for (var i=0; i<numeroDeColumnas; i++){
        $(celdaCreci[i]).html($(celdaCreci[i]).html().toString()+"%")
    }            
})
```

Here is how I load it:

```
.controller('CM_ventasCombosDamaCtrl', function($scope, $state, cssInjector, $http, trucos) {
```

Here is how I use it:

```
trucos.agregarSignoPorcentajeAFila('CRECI', 4);
```

Comment: You have to use factory name instead of module name like :  **.controller('CM_ventasCombosDamaCtrl', function($scope, $state, cssInjector, $http, agregarSignoPorcentajeAFila)**

Comment: Ok, I've done that, still no luck.
When I want to use it would I say agregarSignoPorcentajeAFila('CRECI', 4) or trucos.agregarSignoPorcentajeAFila('CRECI', 4) ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject the factory not the module to the controller,

```
controller('CM_ventasCombosDamaCtrl', function($scope, $state, cssInjector, $http, agregarSignoPorcentajeAFila) {
}
```

Comment: When I want to use it would I say agregarSignoPorcentajeAFila('CRECI', 4) or trucos.agregarSignoPorcentajeAFila('CRECI', 4) ?

Comment: after injecting it the way you suggest

Comment: @quelquecosa you got it sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module("app", []);

myApp.factory('MathService', function() {
    var factory = {};
    factory.multiply = function(a, b) {
        return a * b
    }
    return factory;
});

myApp.controller('CalcController', function($scope, MathService) {
    $scope.mult = function(a) {
        $scope.result = MathService.multiply(a,a);
    }
});
```